# Set property value from FormClosing event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ToolStripButton on my main form and a click event attached to it, on click it will open a dialog and sets toolStripButton's Checked state as 'true'. 
On the FormClosing event of the form that gets open-up from the above click, trying to set the same toolStripButton's Checked state as 'false'.
But the state remains as 'true' always.

```
toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!toolStripButton1.Checked)
        {
            toolStripButton1.Checked = true;
            RevisionTools revTools = new RevisionTools(); 
            revTools.ShowDialog();
        }
}
```

Created a Property like below:

```
public bool revEditState
    {
        get{return this.toolStripButton1.Checked;}
        set{this.toolStripButton1.Checked = value;}
    }
```

And the Dialog that gets open on click:

```
public partial class RevisionTools : Form
{
    public RevisionTools()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void RevisionTools_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        mainForm.revEditState = false;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of setting a property value? It is a WinForms application.

Comment: You are setting new object's (mainForm) property to false. not original one's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting it on a new instance of the MainForm. You will need to pass the instance of the MainForm when opening the dialog or you could do this in the MainForm itself after the ShowDialog.

In your example performing this on the ShowDialog would be a better approach.

```
RevisionTools revTools = new RevisionTools(); 
revTools.ShowDialog();
this.revEditState = false;
```

Note: You can also catch the result of the Dialog as DialogResult to conditionally set this value. i.e. If the user clicked OK or Cancel on the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's staying true because in your FormClosing event, your setting revEditState to false in an entirely new instance on mainForm. You could either pass the variable through to the secondary form as a reference, or assign the FormClosing Event in your main form, like so;

```
revTools.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(RevisionTools_FormClosing);
```

You will need to move "RevisionTools_FormClosing" to your main form.